# Values are overriding to same values in python lists when I use append

Tags: python, mysql, append

my program:

```
values = []
for i in 10:
  values.append({0,1,2,3,4,i})
```

the result is

```
  values[0] = [0,1,2,3,4]  
  values[1] = [0,1,2,3,4]  
  values[2] = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

but the result should be :

```
values[0] = [0,1,2,3,4,0]
values[1] = [0,1,2,3,4,1]
values[2] = [0,1,2,3,4,2]
```

in each sub list the same values is repeated only once..
this array i.e values[0] is to use in python

```
  str = """INSERT INTO tbl_user_custom_adjustments (col1, col2, col3,col4,col5, col6) VALUES {}"""

  str=str.format(tuple(data))
```

the result query is :

```
   INSERT INTO tbl_user_custom_adjustments (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) VALUES (0,1,2,3,4)
```

but the expected result should be:

```
    INSERT INTO tbl_user_custom_adjustments (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) VALUES (0,1,2,3,4,0)
```

Comment: Your example gives `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are saving them in a set() which takes only unique values, change them to [].
Also use range not only 10
like

```
values = []
for i in range(0,10):
  values.append([0,1,2,3,4,i]) 
print(values)
```

Comment: Even though `for i in rage(0, 100)` is quite funny, it should be `range`

Comment: Thank you so much sir this worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Having run this, I believe that using the append function in this case doesnt allow repeats, here was my results.

```
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9}]
```

Comment: Thank you sir previous reply solved my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Using set will remove the duplicate instead use tuple or list
And also use range function in for loop

```
values=[]
for i in range(10):
    values.append([0,1,2,3,4,i])
print(values)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
values=print([[0,1,2,3,4,i] for i in range(10)])
```